# Dynamically Centering Filtered Node within SVG Element in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I am working to add filter functionality to my d3 graph. When the user searches for a specific node based on label or id, I want to re-render the graph and show the entire graph again but I want the filtered node to sit in the center of the svg element.

[image]

here is what I have the helped it to be centered:

```
 // I get the width and height of the SVG element:
   var svgWidth = parseInt(svg.style("width").replace(/px/, ""), 10);
   var svgHeight = parseInt(svg.style("height").replace(/px/, ""), 10);

 // I get the center of the svg:
    var centerX = svgWidth / 2;
    var centerY = svgHeight / 2;

     _.forEach(nodes, function(e) {
          // get the full node (with x and y coordinates) based on the id
           var nodeObject = g.node(nodeId); 

          // I look for matches between the nodeId or label and search word
           if (searchInput) {
                if (nodeObject.id === parseInt(searchInput, 10) || nodeObject.label.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchInput.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                                    searchedNodes.push(nodeObject);
                                    console.log(searchedNodes);
                            }
                    }
              }

              // after looping through all the nodes rendered
              if (searchedNodes.length > 0) {
                    //var width = searchedNodes[0].elem.getBBox().width;
                    //var height =  searchedNodes[0].elem.getBBox().height;
                    ctrl.selectedNode = searchedNodes[0];
                    var offsetX = centerX - searchedNodes[0].x;
                    var offsetY = centerY - searchedNodes[0].y;
                    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + offsetX + "," + offsetY + ")" + "scale(" + 3 + ")");

                     // this line here is incorrect syntax and breaks the build, essentially stopping the script from running
                     // the graph renders correctly when this line is here
                    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + offsetX + "," + offsetY + ")").scale(2).event;
                 }
```

This is what the graph looks like with the line above that breaks the script included.

[image]

When I removed that line, it doesn't center, almost looking like over-renders the graph. Obviously I will need to remove the line of code above that is incorrect but does anybody no why the graph doesn't render correctly in this case?:

[image]

```
          // get the user input and re-render the graph
            elem.find(".search").bind("keyup", function (e:any) {
                var searchInput;
                if (e["keyCode"] === 13) {
                    searchedNodes = [];
                    searchInput = scope["searchInput"];
                    currentFilteredNode = null;
                    enterKeyPressed = true;
                    renderGraph(searchInput);
                    }

                if (e["keyCode"] === 8) {
                    searchedNodes = [];
                    searchInput = scope["searchInput"];
                    currentFilteredNode = null;
                    renderGraph(searchInput);
                }
            });

// if there is searchInput and at least one matching node sort the nodes
// by id and then select and center the first matching one
if (searchInput && searchedNodes.length > 0) {
       searchedNodes.sort(function (node1:any, node2:any) {
                            return node1.id - node2.id;
                    });

                    // make sure the noResultsMessage does not get shown on the screen if there are matching results
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope["noResultsMessage"] = false;
                    });

                    ctrl.selectedNode = searchedNodes[0];
                    offsetX = centerX - searchedNodes[0].x;
                    offsetY = centerY - searchedNodes[0].y;
                    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + offsetX  + "," + offsetY + ")" + "scale(" + 3 + ")");
}

                 // the only other zoom and this runs just on page load
                 zoom = d3.behavior.zoom();

                 zoom.on("zoom", function() {
                    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + (<any>d3.event).translate + ")" + "scale(" + (<any>d3.event).scale + ")");

           // this scales the graph - it runs on page load and whenever the user enters a search input, which re-renders the whole graph
           var scaleGraph = function(useAnimation:any) {
                var graphWidth = g.graph().width + 4;
                var graphHeight = g.graph().height + 4;
                var width = parseInt(svg.style("width").replace(/px/, ""), 10);
                var height = parseInt(svg.style("height").replace(/px/, ""), 10);
                var zoomScale = originalZoomScale;
                // Zoom and scale to fit        
                if (ctrl.autoResizeGraph === "disabled") {
                    zoomScale = 1;
                } else {
                    // always scale to canvas if set to fill or if auto (when larger than canvas)   
                    if (ctrl.autoResizeGraph === "fill" || (graphWidth > width || graphHeight > height)) {
                        zoomScale = Math.min(width / graphWidth, height / graphHeight);
                    }
                }

                var translate;

                if (direction.toUpperCase() === "TB") {
                    // Center horizontal + align top (offset 1px)
                    translate = [(width / 2) - ((graphWidth * zoomScale) / 2) + 2, 1];
                } else if (direction.toUpperCase() === "BT") {
                    // Center horizontal + align top (offset 1px)
                    translate = [(width / 2) - ((graphWidth * zoomScale) / 4) + 2, 1];
                } else if (direction.toUpperCase() === "LR") {
                    // Center vertical (offset 1px)
                    translate = [1, (height / 2) - ((graphHeight * zoomScale) / 2)];
                } else if (direction.toUpperCase() ===  "RL") {
                    // Center vertical (offset 1px)
                    translate = [1, (height / 2) - ((graphHeight * zoomScale) / 4)];
                } else {
                    // Center horizontal and vertical
                    translate = [(width / 2) - ((graphWidth * zoomScale) / 2), (height / 2) - ((graphHeight * zoomScale) / 2)];
                }

                zoom.center([width / 2, height / 2]);
                zoom.size([width, height]);

                zoom.translate(translate);
                zoom.scale(zoomScale);

                // If rendering the first time, then don't use animation
                zoom.event(useAnimation ? svg.transition().duration(500) : svg);
            };
```

CODE FOR FILTERING THE NODES:

```
  // move to the left of the searchedNodes array when the left arrow is clicked
            scope["filterNodesLeft"] = function () {
                filterNodesIndex--;
                if (filterNodesIndex < 0) {
                    filterNodesIndex = searchedNodes.length - 1;
                }
                currentFilteredNode = searchedNodes[filterNodesIndex];
                runScaleGraph = true;
                number = 1;
                renderGraph();
            };

            // move to the right of the searchNodes array when the right arrow is clicked
            scope["filterNodesRight"] = function () {
                filterNodesIndex++;
                if (filterNodesIndex > searchedNodes.length - 1) {
                    filterNodesIndex = 0;
                }
                currentFilteredNode = searchedNodes[filterNodesIndex];
                runScaleGraph = true;
                number = 1;
                renderGraph();
            };

  // get the current filteredNode in the searchNodes array and center it
  // when the graph is re-rendered
  if (currentFilteredNode) {
                    ctrl.selectedNode = currentFilteredNode;
                    offsetX = centerX - currentFilteredNode.x;
                    offsetY = centerY - currentFilteredNode.y;
                    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + offsetX + "," + offsetY + ")");
                    runScaleGraph = false;
                }
```

Comment: Yes, all nodes sit within g.nodes and then each node has the g.node class. I do have subGraph functionality so that new set of nodes sit within the container nodes. I'm looking to center whatever node is matching from the search input in the above image.I've included the DOM layout in the image above as well. Is this possible? Thanks for the help

Comment: When you script throws an error (as in the first screen shot) is the visual output what you expect it to be? Do you have other code adjusting the transform of svgGroup? What happens if you step through your code in a debugger if you comment out your line causing the null pointer/reference?

Comment: Yea the first screen shot with the script throwing the error is the expected output. I just want each selected node to be centered. I then have the option if there is more then one matching search result that the user can click to go through the matching results. This code is part of a large angular component but I have added the main code, including the area where other zooms are being called.

Comment: From what I can tell in the debugger, when a user enters search input and renderGraph is called again, the matching nodes are pushed into a "searchedNodes' array, then sorted by lowest id first, then the first node is selected and should be centered in the svg. It seems to be running once. I can't seem to tell if the scaleGraph is causing the svgGroup translate attribute call to be incorrect or not? I added some additional code to my original post.Thanks again

Comment: I think the error is a red herring. You are removing "scale" from the transform immediately prior to erroring out. Edited answer below.

Comment: Yeah Jamil, that is correct. I was just coming to post that I noticed when I changed the scale to 1 (or remove it completely) and stop the scaleGraph function from running on user search, I'm able to center the container nodes and some sub nodes, although a couple leaf nodes don't center which is weird. The only thing that has changed now is when the search results   come back and there is more then one result the user has the option to click and move to the other nodes..which aren't centering. Would you know why that would be? Pretty much the same code as on initial search.

Comment: I added that code I mentioned above when filtering the nodes. Curious if you would have an idea why that wouldn't center the currently filtered node. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it:

```
             // zoom in on the searched or filtered node
              function zoomOnNode (node:any) {

                // get the width and height of the svg
                var svgWidth = parseInt(svg.style("width").replace(/px/, ""), 10);
                var svgHeight = parseInt(svg.style("height").replace(/px/, ""), 10);

                // loop through all the rendered nodes (these nodes have x and y coordinates)
                for (var i = 0; i < renderedNodes.length; i++) {

                    // if the first matching node passed into the function
                    // and the renderedNode's id match get the 
                    // x and y coordinates from that rendered node and use it to calculate the svg transition
                    if (node.id === renderedNodes[i].id) {
                            var translate = [svgWidth / 2 -  renderedNodes[i].x, svgHeight / 2 - renderedNodes[i].y];
                            var scale = 1;
                            svg.transition().duration(750).call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
                    }
                }
            }

     // listen for the enter key press, get all matching nodes and pass in the first matching node in the array to the zoomOnNode function
     elem.find(".search").bind("keyup", function (e:any) {
                var searchInput;
                if (e["keyCode"] === 13) {
                    searchedNodes = [];
                    searchInput = scope["searchInput"];
                    enterKeyPressed = true;
                    if (searchInput) {
                        // recursively get all matching nodes based on search input
                        getMatchingNodes(ctrl.nodes, searchInput);

                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            // show the toggle icons if searchedNodes.length is greater then 1
                            scope["matchingNodes"] = searchedNodes.length;
                            scope["noResultsMessage"] = false;

                            if (searchedNodes.length > 0) {
                                var firstNode = searchedNodes[0];
                                ctrl.selectedNode = firstNode;
                                zoomOnNode(firstNode);
                            } else if (searchedNodes.length === 0) {
                                    ctrl.selectedNode = null;
                                    // add the noResultsMessage to the screen
                                    scope["noResultsMessage"] = true;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to find the x and y coordinates of your target node, and set the transform attribute of your group with class 'output' accordingly. You will also need to know the width and height of 'output' in order to position it such that your target node is in the center.

```
//when diagram is initially displayed
var output = d3.select('.output');
var bbox = output.getBBox();
var centerX = bbox.width * .5;  
var centerY = bbox.height * .5;


//in your block where you find a node matches the filter
    if (node.label.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
       var offsetX = centerX - node.x;
       var offsetY = centerY - node.y;
       output.attr('transform', 'translate(' + offsetX + ',' + offsetY + ')');    
    }
```

Depending on the node's registration point, you may also need to take in to account the node's width and height to make sure we are directly centered on the node. For example, if the registration point is the top left of the node, you would want to add half the nodes width and half the nodes height to the offset.

-- Edit --

In the following line:

```
svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + offsetX + "," + offsetY + ")" + "scale(" + 3 + ")");
```

by including "scale(" + 3 + ")" so you are scaling your entire graph - you are not 'zooming in' on the place you have centered, rather the content itself is bigger and so offsetX and offsetY are not the correct cordinates to center on.

The reason things look better when you add that other line, is that you are removing the scale.

```
svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + offsetX + "," + offsetY + ")");
```

So, we are back to the default scale, immediately prior to your error being thrown.

If you want to scale, you'll need to multiply offsetX and offsetY by whatever you want to scale by.

If you do not want to scale, just remove

```
"scale(" + 3 + ")"
```

Comment: I am seeing that break my graph, and it doesn't center within the svg element. I need the whole graph above to stay together with the matching node sliding into the center of the SVG element.

Comment: I updated my initial post to show what I have working somewhat. Thanks